# Fazer loop de jSON com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte jSON

```
{
"nome": "Alisson",
"nome": "Bruno",
"nome": "Junior",
"nome": "Nicolly",
"nome": "José",
"nome": "Greice",
"idade": "20",
"idade" : "21",
"idade" : "29",
"idade" : "14",
"idade" : "11",
"idade" : "20"
}
```

Quero fazer um loop com todos. Qual a melhor solução com a linguagem PHP.

Comment: Quer fazer o loop em PHP? ou em Javascript? Já tem o loop na linguagem que quer ou precisa converter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Passo 1: Transformar o JSON em `Array` usando `json_decode()`;
2. Passo 2: Usar `foreach` no `Array`previamente gerado.

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer é fazer um loop nos campos do objeto você pode fazer seguindo a seguinte implementação.

```
$objeto = json_decode('{
"nome": "Alisson",
"idade":"19",
"profissao":"programador"
}', true);



foreach($objeto as $item){
   print $item. "\n";
}
```

A função `json_decode()` do PHP Transforma uma String `JSON` em um Objeto `Array` do PHP o Primeiro parâmetro recebe a string o segundo recebe um valor booleano que você informará se seu objeto será do tipo `Array` Ou `StDclass`.

por fim você acessa cada campo com um `foreach`, a variável item é o campo correspondente ao loop

> Você pode ver seu exemplo [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/042c6a9f7f63fdad520a2cadc7ef7fc182a40705).