# PHP não está exibindo resultado do array

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou com o código:

```
<?php

$d = json_decode($output);

?>
```

A variavel **$output** envia dados jSON para o PHP. Para vocês entenderem melhor essa variavel, vou postar o retorno dela

```
object(stdClass)#1 (6) {
  ["nome_1"]=>
  string(14) "Alisson Acioli"
  ["cpf_1"]=>
  string(11) "XXXXXXXXXX"
  ["nascimento_1"]=>
  string(10) "2014-07-19"
  ["nome_2"]=>
  string(14) "Alisson Acioli"
  ["cpf_2"]=>
  string(11) "XXXXXXXXXX"
  ["nascimento_2"]=>
  string(10) "2014-07-25"
}
```

O que eu quero fazer é fazer um loop com os dados retornados. Eu tenho exibir fazendo

```
<?php

echo $d['nome_1'];

?>
```

só que a tela fica branca, não aparece nada. Na verdade eu gostaria que envez de ter _1, _2 fosse tudo [nome], [cpf] etc.. e eu ia fazendo o loop depois. O código que gera o jSON é o seguinte

```
<?php
$SQLResults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$verificacao}");

                $i = 0;

                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($SQLResults)){

                    $i++;

                    foreach($this->dados["dados"]["show"] as $val){

                        $Resultados[$val.'_'.$i] = $data[$val];
                    }

                }

                echo json_encode($Resultados);
?>
```

Comment: O json é valido? é o mesmo json dessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26768/fazer-loop-de-json-com-php)

Comment: Sim, é tudo como descrito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem dois problemas e não apenas um.

O primeiro e mais importante é quanto ao fato de você estar vendo uma tela branca pois você deveria estar vendo:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in path\to\file.php on line X

Obviamente que com o *path* de localização para seu arquivo e a linha correspondente ao seu **echo**.

Isso significa que seus alertas de erro estão ou desativados ou muito baixos para exibir o erro.

Durante o desenvolvimento é uma boa prática habilitar a exibição de todos os erros possíveis, iniciando o script com:

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );

error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Caso você tem qualquer versão do PHP que não a 5.3.x

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // Especificamente para o PHP 5.3.x
```

O segundo problema, que é o que você mais está interessado, é sobre o porquê de não funcionar como você esperaria que funcionasse.

Ocorre que você está tratando um **objeto** como um **array**. Vê a expressão *stdClass Object*? Então, [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode), por padrão, retorna um objeto stdClass, que é uma classe nativa do PHP.

Apesar dos objetos dessa classe serem iteráveis, tal qual um array convencional, assim como qualquer objeto (desde que esse cumpra alguns requisitos que não vêm ao caso do tópico), **e** de existirem meios para que qualquer objeto também possa ser acessado através da notação de colchetes de um array, por ironia, a *stdClass* não o pode ser.

No entanto, a própria [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode) oferece uma alternativa para que ao invés de retornar um objeto as informações estejam estruturadas num array simples, bastando, para isso, que seja informado um segundo argumento como **TRUE**:

```
$data = json_decode( $output, TRUE );
```

Você conseguiria o mesmo resultado forçando o *cast* da variável para array:

```
$data = (array) json_decode( $json );
```

Comment: Entendido e Resolvido!

Answer (score 4):

Utilize o `json_decode` com o segundo argumento setado em `true`:

```
$d = json_decode($output, true);
```

Irá te retornar um array associativo e você poderá iterá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

O retorno é um objeto, você já resolveu mais uma outra solução seria usar um foreach para percorrer ele.

```
foreach($d as $dados){
 echo $dados->nome.' - '.$dados->cpf_1.' - etc...<br>';
}
```