# Editar categorias e tags no front end do WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando montar uma página para edição de categorias, tags e *custom taxonomies* via *front end*. Porém, agora não consigo achar a função correta para submeter a atualização dos campos.

O código até o momento:

```
<?php

/*Template Name: Page Template Editar Cetegoria*/
get_header(); ?>

<section class="conteudo-geral">
<section class="conteudo" style="width: 990px" role="main">

<?php
$pid = $_REQUEST [ 'pid' ];
$taxonomia = get_term_by('id', $pid, 'category', 'ARRAY_A');

$nome_taxonomia = $taxonomia->name;
$descrição_taxonomia = $taxonomia->description;
?>      

<form action="" method="post">

<tr class="form-field form-required">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="name">Nome</label></th>
<td><input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="4Cast" size="40" aria-required="true">
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="description">Descrição</label></th>
<td><textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5" cols="50" class="large-text">    </textarea><br>
</td>
</tr>

<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Atualizar"></p>
</form>

</section>
</secrion>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa problema resolvido! Vou postar a solução para ajudar a quem quer que deseje realizar a mesma coisa.

Link de edição na pagina da categoria:

```
<?php
    $catID = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    //Obtem o ID da categoria visualisada.
?>

<form class="editar-categoria" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/editar-categoria/?editar-categoria=<?php echo $catID; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="editar-categoria" value="<?php echo $catID; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Editar Categoria"/>
</form>
```

Agora o modelo de pagina de edição de categoria:

```
<?php 
    /*Template Name: Page Template Editar Cetegoria*/
    get_header(); 
?>

<section class="conteudo-geral">
    <section class="conteudo" style="width: 990px" role="main">
        <?php
            $categoria_id = isset( $_GET['editar-categoria'] ) ? intval( $_GET['editar-categoria'] ) : 0;
            //pega o id da categoria da pagina anterior
            $terms = get_term_by('id', $categoria_id, 'category', 'ARRAY_A');
            //pega os dados da categoria

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                $category_id = get_cat_ID($terms['name']);
                $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
                //pega o link da categoria para fazer redirecionamento da pagina no final   

                $term_name = $_POST['nome'];
                $term_description = $_POST['descricao'];
                //pega os dados dos campos de formulario

                $result = wp_update_term( $categoria_id, 'category', array(
                        'name' => $term_name,
                        'description' => $term_description ) );
                //função do wordpress para editar categoria

                if ( array_key_exists( 'term_id', $result ) ) {
                    echo true;
                } 
                else {
                    echo false;
                }

                wp_redirect( $category_link );
                exit;
            }
        ?>      

        <form action="" method="post">
            Nome da Categoria: 
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo get_cat_name($categoria_id); ?>" size="75" required/>
            <br>
            Descrição da Categoria:
            <br>                            
            <input type="text" name="descricao" value="<?php echo $terms['description']; ?>" size="75" required/>
            <br>
            <br>

            <!-- Caso precisar editar qualquer custom filed 
            Custom Field:
            <label for="category_custom_1order">Custom Field: </label>
            <br>
            <input name="category_custom_1order" id="category_custom_1order" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option( 'category_custom_1order_' . $categoria_id); ?>" /> -->

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    </section>
</secrion>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

A função que procura é [**`wp_insert_term`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term).

Observações:

- É importante desenvolver com o [*error report*  ligado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26779/201), você veria que aquele `$pid = $_REQUEST [ 'pid' ];` dá um *warning*.
- Falta adicionar uma [verificação de segurança](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field), senão qualquer *spam bot* vai abusar do `<form>`.
- A `form action` tem que apontar pra própria página.
- É melhor usar nomes de `fields` personalizados, para não correr o risco de conflitos com nomes usados pelo WordPress.

Segue um exemplo bem simples, usando uma pequena parte da estrutura [deste tutorial](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-built-in-contact-form-for-your-wordpress-theme) (vale a pena conferir o tuturial inteiro, note que ele não usa *nonce*):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page Template Editar Categoria 
 */    
get_header() ?>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <?php the_post() ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID() ?>" class="post">
                <div class="entry-content"><?php
                    /**
                     * Verifica se o FORM foi enviado
                     */
                    if( isset( $_POST [ 'submitted' ] ) ) {
                        /**
                         * Verifica segurança
                         */
                        if( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce_form_sopt_28484'], 'nonce_form_sopt_28484' ) ) {
                            # FALTA conferir se a categoria existe
                            # FALTA definir se pode ser categorias-filhas 
                            $term_id = wp_insert_term(
                              $_POST [ 'nome' ], // the term 
                              'category', // the taxonomy
                              array(
                                'description'=> $_POST [ 'descricao' ]
                              )
                            );
                            if ( !is_wp_error( $term_id ) ) {
                                # DEBUG
                                printf( 
                                    'Categoria <strong>%s (%s)</strong> inserida com sucesso. IDs:<br /><pre><code>%s</code></pre>', 
                                    $_POST[ 'nome' ],
                                    $_POST[ 'descricao' ],
                                    print_r( $term_id, true ) 
                                );
                            } else {
                                # DEBUG
                                printf( 'Erro ao gravar:<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $term_id, true ) );
                            }
                        }
                    } ?>      
                    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'nonce_form_sopt_28484', 'nonce_form_sopt_28484' ); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                    <p>
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                        <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" placeholder="O nome da categoria" size="40" aria-required="true">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
                        <textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" rows="5" cols="50" class="large-text" placeholder="Descrição da categoria"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p class="submit">
                        <button type="submit">Criar categoria</button>
                    </p>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- .entry-content ->
            </div><!-- .post-->
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar() ?>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: demo]

Comment: Agradeço muito a resposta, ela possibilitará a melhora de muitos formulários!!!

Porem, a função wp_insert_term, serva para adicionar uma nova taxonomia, o centro da duvida é como editar a taxonomia!

Em meu código, já consegui criar a pagina de edição que recupera os valores do nome e descrição da taxonomia do banco de dados, a função que preciso agora, é a que faz a atualização destes valores no banco de dados, apos o submit!

Comment: Oi, então por favor atualize sua pergunta com o código que está usando.

Comment: Este é exatamente o código que estou tentando construir para editar a categoria.

Vou explicar melhor: Tenho uma pagina em que o usuário pode adicionar uma categoria, via front end. Ex: Nome da Categoria => Maria Descrição da Categoria: Maria é uma moça legal!. No pagina da categoria existe um link que redireciona para a pagina que contem o código acima, que deve ser para o usuário editar a categoria. Ex. Descrição da Categoria: Maria é uma moça legal. Mudar para: Maria é uma moça chata. Clica em submit e a categoria é atualizada. É isso que eu não estou conseguindo realizar.